# What does "work on side gigs" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "work on side gigs" mean?

Here is the context:

> Employees who remained at Yahoo struggled to motivate themselves amid all the uncertainty. Some **worked on side gigs** in the office. Many feared more layoffs, with or without a sale."

[Source.](http://money.cnn.com/2016/07/25/technology/Yahoo-marissa-Mayer-what-went-wrong/index.html)

Comment: Have you looked up *side* and *gig* in a dictionary? What does that tell you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this was cross posted on ELL and [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/339895/what-does-work-on-side-gigs-mean). Please only post questions on one site.

Comment: @Catija - I agree that questions should only be posted on one site. That said, I'm surprised you'd vote to close here rather than there. This seems to be more of a learner's question than a "serious linguists" question. Seems odd that it was closed promptly here and left open there. _C'est la vie_.

Comment: @J.R. I can't VTC on ELU and I felt that the answer there was more thorough than the one here, so I felt that it would be better if that was the one that remained.

Comment: @Cat - Poor use of pronouns on my part. I guess I just meant to say that I'm surprised the question was closed here and left open there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that they were working on other jobs at the same time, or doing other things in the office.